# loaderManager and AdapterView showing error

Tags: android

The below code is showing error.

```
public class CalendarDetailActivity extends ListActivity 
implements  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener 
{     private static final int LOADER_DETAIL = 101;      
          SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    int mCalendarId;

     }
```

In eclipse IDE, its showing red underline. How to fix it?Help me :-(

Comment: do whatever they error tells you to do

Comment: Well, if i take the cursor over LoaderManager it gives suggestion-"fix project". If i take cursor over AdapterView, it shows 3 options- 1. "create interface 'adapterView' 2.Change to adapter(android.widget).

Comment: all you need to do is implement the methods those interfaces require just like Jeffrey Klardie said

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the red line, you should see the error. Alternatively, you can open the 'problems' view to show all project errors.

In this case, I'd say the problem is you don't implement any functions from the classes that you claim to implement.